# I need to sync playlists automatically between two distant computers

Tags: itunes

Now I am using DropBox to sync Music between two computers and I am using the
"Automatically add to Itunes" folder to add the folders to Itunes on the distant computer.
I have two problems that I would like to solve.

First Problem is that when I recieve the songs in the distant computer I would like to have them added in one playlist automatically.

I solve this with a naive way where I change the Genre of the songs to an unique name, which can then be sorted in a Smart Playlist in the distant Computer.

Second Problem is that I add the songs using copy and paste into the DropBox Folder. I would like to have it automatically done to me that if I add songs to Playlist X the songs are copied in (DropBox) folder Y.

Comment: For people who still need something similar..Spotify solved my Problem :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need some custom scripts in order to do that. Have a look at this page:

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/scriptpal.php

However, I think that it this is only available for Mac.

Comment: Yeah it is indeed only availible for mac. I figured out that i would have to use custom scripts to do that. I would probably need another AppleScript Program to work on Windows. But thanks though